# Python & Pandas: Strange behavior when Pandas plot histogram to a specific ax

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I want to plot pandas histogram to an axis, but the behavior is really strange. I don't know what's wrong here.

```
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,3))
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,3))
fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,3))

# 1. This works
df['speed'].hist()

# 2. This doens't work
df['speed'].hist(ax=ax2)

# 3. This works
data = [1,2,3,5,6,2,3,4]
temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
temp_df.hist(ax=ax2)
```

The error jupyter notebook returns is:

---

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-d629de832772> in <module>()
      7 
      8 # This doens't work
----> 9 df['speed'].hist(ax=ax2)
     10 
     11 # # This works

D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.pyc in hist_series(self, by, ax, grid, xlabelsize, xrot, ylabelsize, yrot, figsize, bins, **kwds)
   2953             ax = fig.gca()
   2954         elif ax.get_figure() != fig:
-> 2955             raise AssertionError('passed axis not bound to passed figure')
   2956         values = self.dropna().values
   2957 

AssertionError: passed axis not bound to passed figure
```

The pandas source code is here:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/d38ee272f3060cb884f21f9f7d212efc5f7656a8/pandas/tools/plotting.py#L2913

Totally have no idea what's wrong with my code.

Comment: I am having this same problem too while trying to display a Pandas.hist() plot into a PyQt5 Ui. Really frustrating. None of the suggested solutions worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that pandas determines which is the active figure by using `gcf()` to get the "current figure".  When you create several figures in a row, the "current figure" is the last one created.  But you are trying to plot to an earlier one, which causes a mismatch.

However, as you can see on line 2954 of the source you linked to, pandas will look for an (undocumented) `figure` argument.  So you can make it work by doing `df['speed'].hist(ax=ax2, figure=fig2)`.  A comment in the `pandas` source notes that this is a "hack until the plotting interface is a bit more unified", so I wouldn't rely on it for anything too critical.

The other solution is to not create a new figure until you're ready to use it.  In your example above, you only use figure 2, so there's no need to create the others.  Of course, that is a contrived example, but in a real-life situation, if you have code like this:

```
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,3))
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,3))
fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,3))

something.hist(ax=ax1)
something.hist(ax=ax2)
something.hist(ax=ax3)
```

You can change it to this:

```
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,3))
something.hist(ax=ax1)

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,3))
something.hist(ax=ax2)

fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,3))
something.hist(ax=ax3)
```

That is, put each section of plotting code right after the code that creates the figure for that plot.

Comment: Me too I encountered this problem, but I've not understood well the answer: _pandas determines which is the active figure_ In the second case, the guy indicated `ax=ax2` but why it is not enough? In the case you put a simple `plot`, and not `hist`, and it works. Why is there a difference between these two functions? Thnaks

Comment: @SPS: Why?  I don't know.  The hack that uses the undocumented `figure` argument appears to exist only in `hist`.  Why that is, I don't know.

Comment: Thank you!! I was very useful to know that you can pass the figure to a pandas plot

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues while trying to plot a Pandas histogram into a PyQt5 Widget (from a UI created using Qt Creator).

The code looked something liked this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


class MplWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())

        vertical_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vertical_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.canvas.axes = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.setLayout(vertical_layout)

index1 = np.random.rand(10000)
data1 = np.random.gamma(2, 2, 10000)

s1 = pd.Series(data1, index=index1)

MplWidget_object = MplWidget_FROM_MY_GUI

s1.hist(ax=MplWidget_object.canvas.axes) # This would throw an error.
pd.DataFrame(s1).hist(ax=MplWidget_object.canvas.axes) # This Works!!!
```

I managed to make it work by converting my pandas.Series into a Dataframe (las two lines of the code)