# Python pandas `Series.hist()`, can't pass `ax` parameter that has different `figure`, but can do so with `DataFrame.hist()`. Desired behaviour?

Tags: python, pandas, histogram, figure, axes

## Edit

It seems that this is not a problem in non-Jupyter-Notebook scripts. It's fine even in IPython (from the commandline). It seems that this is only a problem when using Jupyter Notebook, and only when my second block of code (below in original question) is in a different cell from my first block of code.

But still, (the next sentence makes sense after reading the original question,) if we use `DataFrame.hist()` things work fine even if they're in different Jupyter Notebook cells.

## System versions

- Python 3.5.1
- Pandas 0.18.1

## Original question

I have read [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38342544/python-pandas-strange-behavior-when-pandas-plot-histogram-to-a-specific-ax), because I've been bitten by `AssertionError: passed axis not bound to passed figure`.

```
import numpy
import pandas

index1 = numpy.random.rand(10000)
data1 = numpy.random.gamma(2, 2, 10000)
s1 = pandas.Series(data1, index=index1)

index2 = numpy.random.rand(10000)
data2 = numpy.random.lognormal(0, 1, 10000)
s2 = pandas.Series(data2, index=index2)

subplot = s1.hist(normed=True, bins=100, color="yellow", histtype="stepfilled", alpha=0.5)
```

All that code above is fine, but when I try to plot a histogram for `s2` on the same axes,

```
s2.hist(ax=subplot, normed=True, bins=100, color="green", histtype="stepfilled", alpha=0.5)
```

I get

```
AssertionError: passed axis not bound to passed figure
```

The error is easy enough to understand, and from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38342544/python-pandas-strange-behavior-when-pandas-plot-histogram-to-a-specific-ax) I found out that there is an "undocumented" `figure` argument to `Series.hist()`, so that I can fix the problem with

```
s2.hist(figure=subplot.get_figure(), ax=subplot, normed=True, bins=100, color="green", histtype="stepfilled", alpha=0.5)
```

But this fix seems convoluted. And if it's undocumented, it's even more strange. Can this really be the desired behaviour? For a start, why can't `Series.hist()` just figure out (pun intended) the `figure` of the axes object passed to `ax`? After all, the `DataFrame.hist()` method doesn't seem to have a problem with it. The code below works fine without explicitly passing a `figure` argument to the `hist()` method.

```
d1 = pandas.DataFrame(s1, columns=["data1"])
subplot_array = d1.hist(normed=True, bins=100, color="red", histtype="stepfilled", alpha=0.5)

d2 = pandas.DataFrame(s2, columns=["data2"])
d2.hist(ax=subplot_array, normed=True, bins=100, color="blue", histtype="stepfilled", alpha=0.5)
```

It seems to me that the `Series.hist()` method should be fixed so that it behaves the same way as `DataFrame.hist()`; that is to say, we shouldn't have to pass an explicit `figure` argument to `Series.hist()`, especially if it's undocumented. Do you agree?

Comment: `s2.hist(ax=subplot...)` works as expected (for me) using pandas version 0.18.

Comment: The code you provided works for me without the "convoluted" solution

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Please see edit.

Comment: Maybe it's default behaviour for `Series.hist()` to assume that only one histogram for an axes is ever created because it's a 1D-array while dataframe is 2D. Just speculating though. You should post this at the pandas github if you don't get good answers here.